# retrieve button-name on jsp page servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am developing a jsp application using eclipse.
Currently trying to detect which button is pressed while submitting a form with ajax call.
however the request.getParameter(button-name) returns null within the doPost method of servlet.
below is the code for jsp, ajax call(jquery) and servlet.
//jsp

```
<body>
    <form id="formCreateUser">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4"><label>New User Information</label></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Name : </label> <input type="text" name="txtName"
                        id="txtName" /></td>
                    <td><label>Surname : </label><input type="text"
                        id="txtSurname" name="txtSurname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>User name : </label><input type="text"
                        name="txtUserName" /></td>
                    <td><label>E-mail : </label> <input type="text"
                        name="txtEmail" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Password : </label><input type="password"
                        id="txtPassword" /></td>
                    <td><label>Re-enter password : </label><input type="password"
                        id="txtPassword2" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Is Admin ?</label> <input type="checkbox"
                        value="Admin" name="chkAdmin" id="chkAdmin" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" name="btnSumbit" id="btnSubmit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

//jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'CreateUserServlet',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : $("#formCreateUser").serialize(),
            success : function(data) {
                //something here
            }
        });
        return false;
    });     
});
```

servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (request.getParameter("btnSubmit") != null) {
            System.out.println("It works");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It doesn't work");
        }
}
```

any help is highly appreciated
Regards

Comment: $("#formCreateUser").serialize() will create a URL encoded text string by serializing form values, but not the buttons i guess
try this **data :{btnSumbit:$("#btnSubmit").val()}**

Comment: yes. but for OP's case it will work (as its not for multiple button currently) this will be just a start...

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery part you must send the paramater and it's value, if you display the serialize() method it'wont give you the parameter of btnSubmit, so you must add it to the method like this:
Replace this code :

```
data : $("#formCreateUser").serialize(),
```

By this one :

```
data : $("#formCreateUser").serialize()+"&btnSumbit="+$("#btnSubmit").val(),
```

i hope that it will work for you.

Comment: thank you but it didn't work as Balus explained in the comment.